# NodeJS+express Insert data into table multiple times

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku-postgres

I'm new to nodeJs.

I'm trying to make a simple server(nodeJS + Postgres) that inserts a new row to the DB(based on the URL) every time the URL is called with parameters.
The problem is, the following code works the first time the URL is called but the second time and on it doesn't insert the data in the DB.

How could I make it work every time the URL is called?

Thanks

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const { Client } = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
    connectionString: 'postgres://...........',
    ssl: true,
});



app.get('/item/', (req, res) =>
    (client.connect()
        .then(()=>console.log('sucessful connection to DB'))
        .then(()=>client.query(`INSERT INTO items(id,user) values('${req.query.id}','${req.query.user}')`))
        .then(res.send("user sent"))
        .catch(e=>console.log(e))
        .finally(()=>client.end())))



app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Comment: What error are you getting? what logs?

Comment: Error: Client has already been connected. You cannot reuse a client.
This error appears the second time I call the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reusing the client, and you can't do that. It's better in your case to use a connection [pool](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool).

```
const pool = new Pool({
   connectionString: 'postgres://...........',
   ssl: true,
})

app.get('/item/', (req, res, next) => {

     pool.query('...')
        .then(result => res.send('ok'))
        .catch(next)
})
```

Also, don't concatenate the values, otherwise you're open to SQL injections attacks. Use [parameterized query](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#Parameterized%20query) instead